# i want to convert dataframe into list of list which contains column name in first list and data in others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i want to convert this Dataframe  into list of list

```
Year  Sales  Expenses  Profit
2014  1000   400       200
2015  1170   460       250
2016  660    1120      300
2017  1030   540       350
```

this is the expected output

```
[
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'],
    ['2014', 1000, 400, 200],
    ['2015', 1170, 460, 250],
    ['2016', 660, 1120, 300],
    ['2017', 1030, 540, 350]
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using:

```
print([df.columns.tolist()] + df.values.tolist())
```

Output:

```
[['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses', 'Profit'], [2014, 1000, 400, 200], [2015, 1170, 460, 250], [2016, 660, 1120, 300], [2017, 1030, 540, 350]]
```